# How to search element on one sheet based on another sheet and extract certain values?

Tags: microsoft-excel

Worksheet 1 is a material movement record: it has a column of material names("A1", "A2") and a column of quantity in unit. 
Worksheet 2 is a material package information: it has a column of material names (more material types than worksheet 1) and a column of unit type ("Piece", "Pack", etc). 
I want to use material name A1 in worksheet 1 to search that material A1 in worksheet 2 and copy the corresponding unit type from worksheet 2 and paste it to worksheet 1 separate column that matches the same material as A1. What should I do about this case?

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser, this however is not a script writing service. Can you give an example of what you already tried, so that we can help you with your specific problem? If you don't know how to start, try this: https://www.deskbright.com/excel/using-index-match/. Also sample data always improves your question.

Comment: index-match is the hard way.  This just wants a [vlookup](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/VLOOKUP-function-0BBC8083-26FE-4963-8AB8-93A18AD188A1) solution

Answer (score 0):

For example the first sheet (Movement) has the following:

```
Column A   Column B     Column C
Material1   12         =VLOOKUP(A1,Package!$A$1:$B$12,2,FALSE)
Material2   34          Pack //Example of the result
Material3   45          Box
Material4   67          Piece
Material10  5           Piece
Material12  3           Box
```

In sheet2 (Package) you have

```
Column A    Column B  
Material1   Piece
Material2   Pack
Material3   Box
Material4   Piece
Material5   Piece
Material6   Pack
Material7   Piece
Material8   Pack
Material9   Box
Material10  Piece
Material11  Pack
Material12  Box
```

The formula in Movement Sheet in Column C (in C1 for example):

```
=VLOOKUP(A1,Package!$A$1:$B$12,2,FALSE)`
```

`A1` is the first Material in Movement sheet

`Package!$A$1:$B$12` is all your Data in Package sheet you have to change it to correspond your information (if Package column is <> column B you have to include it in the references and keep $ for absolute references)

`2` is the column number of Pack, Piece...(if column A is Material and column D is the pack column use `4` and `Package!$A$1:$D$12`)

`FALSE` to return the exact match of Material

Drag the formula down the column to fill the remaining rows.

---

INDEX(MATCH) alternative

```
=INDEX(Package!$B$1:$B$12, MATCH(A1, Package!$A$1:$A$12, 0)
```

`Package!$B$1:$B$12` is the column you want the information returned, that is **Unit Type**

`A1` is the name of material you want to look in the lookup table

`Package!$A$1:$A$12` is the column where the material name list is stored

`0` is looking for exact match - the same as `FALSE` from `VLOOKUP`

### Note

INDEX(MATCH) is useful in case there is a new column inserted in reference table.

In this case, `Unit Type` might not be column 2, but become column 3. If you use `VLOOKUP`, you must update the formula (changing 2 to 3). If you use `INDEX(MATCH)` Excel will automatically update the formula for you.